# Differential of a direct product

Tags: differential-geometry

Given two differentiable maps between differential manifolds:

$$f : X \to Y, g : X \to Z,$$

Is $f \times g : X \times X \to Y \times Z$ differentiable?

I think yes. And you get $d(f \times g)_{(x,y)} = d(f)_x \times d(g)_y$?

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct. But I can't give you a 'formal' proof. I'm not sure that fact is provable, but a definition.

Comment: To be (hopfully constructively) pedantic: It's only correct when making use of the fact that $$T_{(x,y)}(X \times X) \cong T_xX \times T_yX,$$ and then it's trivial.
The differentiability can be checked making use of the induced (''product'') atlas that $X \times X$ admits (and has to be proven before you can talk about $d(f \times g)$.

Comment: You can try to prove that a map $f : M \to M_1 \times M_2$ is smooth if and only if the maps $\pi_i \circ f : N \to M_i$ are smooth. (The maps $\pi_i : M_1 \times M_2 \to M_i$ are canonical projections). For its differential look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3670908/cartesian-product-of-embeddings-is-embedding/3671055#3671055) for example.